# error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support

Tags: python, opencv

I was working on a sign language detection project on jupyter notebook. While running the code for live detection I encountered an error as shown below:

> OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-1drr4hl0\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:651: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

The code that caused this error is:

```py
while True: 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)
    
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
    
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                  for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np_with_detections,
                detections['detection_boxes'],
                detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
                detections['detection_scores'],
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                max_boxes_to_draw=5,
                min_score_thresh=.5,
                agnostic_mode=False)

    cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        break
```

NB: I installed OpenCV using using pip install.

Comment: It would be nice if the code in this question could be replaced by a [mre]. Most of this code doesn't really seem relevant for the specific issue, and the relevant imports are missing. I guess that only `cv2.imshow()` is the method causing this error, so only a few lines of code are necessary to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I saw this solution under the comment of the first answer by Karthik Thilakan:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python-headless -y 

pip install opencv-python --upgrade
```

This worked for me in the conda environment.

Answer (score 56):

*This solution seems to work for a majority of users, but not
all. If you are in this case, see the proposed answer by
Sachin Mohan.*

I had the exact same error using yolov5, on Windows 10. Reinstalling the library by typing

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

then

```
pip install opencv-python
```

worked for me.

Comment: Tried as greg245 mentioned with no success. The commands suggested by Karthik Thilakan worked for me

Comment: uninstall+install does not "rebuild the library". it *reinstalls* the package. the real issue is a conflict between multiple packages of opencv, likely one of them being a headless package.

Answer (score 8):

I installed another GPU and finally upgraded to Tensorflow 2 this week and suddenly, the same issue arose. I finally found my mistake and why uninstalling and reinstalling opencv works for some people. The issue is stated clearly in a text file in your opencv-python dist-packages named METADATA.

It states;

> There are four different packages (see options 1, 2, 3 and 4 below) and you should **SELECT ONLY ONE OF THEM**. Do not install multiple different packages in the same environment.

Further, the file says that;

> You should always use these packages if you do not use `cv2.imshow` et al. or you are using some other package (such as PyQt) than OpenCV to create your GUI.

referring to

> Packages for server (headless) environments ... (with) no GUI library dependencies

So, if you run;

```
pip list | grep opencv
```

and the result is more than one opencv version, you've likely found your problem. While an uninstall & reinstall of opencv might solve your problem, a more masterful solution is to simply uninstall the headless version as that is the one that does not care about GUIs, as it should be used in server environments.

Comment: Hit his when I upgraded Tensorflow. pip uninstall opencv-python-headless fixed it. Ubuntu 20.04, python 3.8, Opencv 4.5.4

Answer (score 6):

I had this exact same issue a few weeks back and I'd like to perhaps complement some of the answers touching the *headless* elephant in the room.

My complex project incorporates a few in-house subprojects by other colleagues. These tend to be developed and tested **independently**, so no cross-contamination occurs. However, since one of them used `opencv-python` and another went with `opencv-python-headless`, the final build installed both.

**THIS IS THE PROBLEM!**

Whenever I had both, a number of functions, particularly those pertaining visualisation, now failed. Worse: `pip list` revealed both `opencv-` versions installed! To make matters worse, whenever I uninstalled and installed again `opencv-python` (a simple `--upgrade` never worked, as it claimed the latest version was there and nothing needed upgrading), then it started working. We all hate witchcraft, so...

I went down the compilation rabbit hole and obviously nothing good was there to be found.

## How does `pip` know it?

if you check into your `.venv\Lib\site-packages`, you'll find the following two folders:

- `opencv_python-4.5.4.60.dist-info`
- `opencv_python-headless-4.5.4.60.dist-info`

or whatever your version might be. These are the folders where `pip` gets its metadata from, but not where the actual code is. In fact, you don't do `import opencv-...`, but rather `import cv2`.

**You do `import cv2` in both cases!** In fact, `-headless` is a crippled drop-in for the real thing. So, if you look up in your list, you'll find a `cv2` folder. Both libraries deposit their code in this folder. As we know, when it comes to saving files, the last on the scene wins.

## Order! Order!

(Ok, I miss John Bercow.)

Now, both libraries saving to the same folder, what is the order? Since they don't depend on one another, and in my case where `poetry` is being used to manage dependencies, alphabetical order is the default, and (drumroll) `-headless` comes last.

## Solution

At some point, I just decided to go nuts and remove `-headless` altogether. I am not the CV dev in the team, so I was just grasping for straws , but... it worked! That's when I looked int the whole drop-in thing.

My colleagues were developing with a simple `requirements.txt` file, so when it came to gathering requirements in a nice proper `pyproject.toml` file, I just left the `-headless` option out.

## Bottom line

**You can't have both.** Whenever you have multi-part projects, I highly advise to run through the `pip list` after the environment is built and check for the couple. If you find both, always remove the `-headless`, as it is a subset of the main one.

**Achtung:** check your `.venv\pyvenv.cfg` for a line with:

- `include-system-site-packages = true`

This line means your project will be importing any libraries (other than the standard ones) from your global Python install and if you happen to have the `-headless` in the global environment, you're still in trouble.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when I wrote a similar program, but issue was with different versions of opencv packages.

You can check them with the command:

```
pip list | grep opencv
```

My output was:

> *opencv-contrib-python         4.5.5.62*

> *opencv-python                 4.5.5.62*

> *opencv-python-headless        4.5.4.60*

And it turned out that opencv-python-headless must be version 4.5.4 for the program to run properly. So the solution was to change the opencv-python version to be the same as opencv-python-headless. So in that case you can run:

```
pip install opencv-python==4.5.4.60
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue for me:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python

pip install opencv-contrib-python
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

and then reinstall the OpenCV:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 1):

When I uninstalled and reinstalled OpenCV, the problem went away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to move a set of files to my Windows10 from Ubuntu 18.04 LTD,  and running a cli for inference and the same error as mentioned in the opening post cropped up......I was checking on the versions of Open-CV and Open-CV Headless in both Ubuntu and Windows and they were exactly the same......While it was executing on Ubuntu, it threw the error in Windows......I removed Open-CV Headless and upgraded the Open-CV, and used the same set of commands and Windows started to execute the CLI for inferencing.......

Answer (score 0):

This error is mostly with Pycharm Ide , I resolved it by **changing the project interpreter** None of the given solution in the internet worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

for streamlit cloud use opencv-python-headless
but in other platforms use opencv-python

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. 
Please edit to add further details, such as code, citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. 
You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can also save image with single command and then open it from drive.
cv2.imwrite("TestImage.jpg",img)

No need to waste time on cv2.imshow()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

install opencv-python 4.7.0.68, as opencv-python 4.7.0.72 won't work with your code.

```
    pip uninstall opencv-python
    pip install opencv-python==4.7.0.68
```

Answer (score -2):

pip uninstall opencv-python-headless
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python-headless
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip uninstall opencv-python

pip install opencv-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python

[check out official docs](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#opencv-on-wheels)