# file can't be found when using relative path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

I am doing a vehicle license plate detection and recognition project. My code was working perfectly fine and then all of a sudden it stopped working. It seems as if `opencv` stopped working completely.

This is the error I am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\Python Project VSCode\Code\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("real image", image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1006: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

I am just running a smaller code to get get opencv working. This is the code i am running.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('T2.jpg')
cv2.imshow("real image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling `opencv`. I have even tried in a different IDE but I get the same error. I dont know what to do.

Please help

Comment: Your image is not being read, check if the path is right, you can do `if image is not None` before any tratment

Comment: To be more precise, OpenCV is telling you that the image size is 0 and it cannot do anything with it. So likely the problem comes from the way you read your image. Where is it placed? can you use it's full path?

Comment: Please print out the shape of `image` and share with us.

Comment: learn about **current working directory** and how relative paths are resolved

Comment: the image is in the same file as the code. I have also tried using the path for the image but that gives the same error. @ivan

Comment: `print(os.path.exists("T2.jpg"), repr(os.getcwd()), os.listdir(os.getcwd()))` and report back. and review [mre]. learn to debug your program and follow an issue to its root.

Answer (score 1):

**A workaround: Put images and code in the same directory.**

For example, I create a new folder called `test`, I put a picture named `T2.jpg` in the folder, and then create a new `test.py` file.

[image]

Open this folder with vscode. The code runs without errors.

[image]

---

---

**To answer your comment:**

What folder are you opening in vscode? Is it the folder that contains `main.py` (Like the `test` folder in my answer), in your project this should be the `Code` folder.

If you open the `Python Project VSCode` folder in vscode, and then run the `main.py` (in `Code` folder), there will definitely be an error.

[image]

At this time, you need to specify the path in the code, like the following:

[image]

Comment: This is what I have done. the image is in the same folder as the python file. I have even tried entering the path manually but that gives the same error
@PeterSmith

Comment: https://imgur.com/rtm4M4R here is a link to a picture of the file

Comment: I updated the answer, is it useful?

Comment: okay, I have done that and it is giving me a different error. 
 File "c:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\Python Project VSCode\Code\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("real image", image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1274: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 
2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

Comment: Can you show your error interface? Or the entire interface of vscode. // Or try absolute paths.

Comment: do you want me to screen shot the entire window?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vIdjrGT

Comment: It is recommended that you reinstall the package to see if that resolves the error. `pip uninstall opencv-python `  and  `pip install opencv-python`.  This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120450/error-2unspecified-error-the-function-is-not-implemented-rebuild-the-libra) should help you.

Comment: I tried doing that and it gives the same error. And i just want to say, i really appreciate your help and patience. Have you got any other sollutions to this problem

Comment: I'm sorry for not being able to help. Finally, if you can successfully run the code in an external terminal or other IDE, I recommend filing an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose) on GitHub.