# OpenCV waitKey() throws assertion: Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, yolov5

I have trained a certain model and have the weights (weight.pt) and am able to detect objects from images and videos, but the problem is the webcam is not opening.

In google collab to train my model

```
!git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5 
%cd yolov5
%pip install -qr requirements.txt
%pip install -q roboflow
%pip install torch==1.8.2 torchvision==0.9.2 torchaudio===0.8.2 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/cu111


from roboflow import Roboflow
import torch
import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import Image, clear_output #to display image
import glob
from IPython.display import Image, display



rf_model = Roboflow(model_format="yolov5",notebook="ultralytics")

os.environ['DATASET_DIRECTORY'] = "/content/dataset" #setting environment

//data set
dataset = project.version(5).download("yolov5")

!python train.py --img 640 --batch 16 --epochs 1 --data {dataset.location}/data.yaml --weight yolov5x.pt --cache --worker 2

!python detect.py  --img 640 --source 0 --weigths {path/to custom weights}
```

getting the error

```
 File "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\air\Tool_Object_Detection\yolov5\detect.py", line 114, in run
    for path, im, im0s, vid_cap, s in dataset:
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\air\Tool_Object_Detection\yolov5\utils\dataloaders.py", line 406, in __next__
    if not all(x.is_alive() for x in self.threads) or cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):  # q to quit
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1333: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvWaitKey'
```

Then I tried ..

In the cam.py file

```
import cv2
import torch
import numpy as np

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5','custom','odec\\best_v5s_640_500_21_9.pt')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret,frame = cap.read()

    result = model(frame)
    cv2.imshow('YOLO',np.squeeze(result.render()))
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above is the code that I tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120450/error-2unspecified-error-the-function-is-not-implemented-rebuild-the-libra)

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the code the problem lies with the package
opencv-python==4.6.0.66,
changing the function code works, install lower version

Comment: no... you installed a headless variant, or it was installed as the dependency of another package. check `pip list` -- `Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support.` indicates this -- prebuilt packages of `opencv-python`, be it 4.6.0 or any other version, always come with gui support. `opencv-python-headless` does *not*.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to dependency issues. To fix this:

Step 1: Uninstall the following libraries using these commands:

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python

pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python-headless

pip uninstall opencv-python
```

Step 2: Install opencv

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).