how to use cv2.imshow()?
Code:
cv2.imshow('E:\Open_CV\opencv\images', img)

error:
error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1272: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support.

I did install opencv-python-4.9.0.80.
Installing collected packages: numpy, opencv-python.
Successfully installed numpy-1.24.4 opencv-python-4.9.0.80
How to display the image using cv2.imshow?

first you need rtfm. then check fuctions like imread and then imshow.

I found a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120450/error-2unspecified-error-the-function-is-not-implemented-rebuild-the-libra. You can try out the solutions suggested.


create a new venv in cmd (change your terminal from powershell to cmd in vscode)
Activate the venv you created
then --> pip install opencv-python

